# Catch the Webkit redirect in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, webkit

I have a WebKit object with special auth page, and after succeed auth user is being redirected to special URL with token, for example `http://example.com?token=foo`

How to catch the WebKit redirect in Cocoa and check the final URL for the token?

Answer (score 0):

Please search the documentation before posting. A quick search of the docs for "[webkit redirect](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/search/?q=webkit%20redirect)" reveals the [WebFrameLoadDelegate protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebFrameLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) as the top hit. The very first paragraph of that doc says (emphasis mine):

> Delegates are notified when a frame load starts, when a page title or
>   icon is loaded, **when a redirect occurs**, ...

An in-page search reveals the convenient "Client and Server **Redirect** Messages" heading, which shows a collection of redirect-related delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks! But there is no information about how to delegate the `didReceiveServerRedirectForProvisionalLoadForFrame` to my WebView.

Comment: I've added https://gist.github.com/2900219 to my AppDelegate.h, but nothing happens...

Comment: Did you set the app delegate as your WebView's delegate?

Comment: I found a solution: `[authDialog setFrameLoadDelegate:self];` in the AppDelegate.m. But what does it mean?

Comment: You are not doing your homework. You're going to need to read the introductory Cocoa documentation Apple provides to get a good idea of how all this fits together. Specifically to delegates, what they are, and how to use them: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html  -- DO YOUR HOMEWORK.